# Ocaml compilation error in AIX 6.1

Tags: compiling, aix, make

I meet the following error when I try to compile Ocaml on my server running AIX 6.1 :

```
"../Makefile.shared", line 39: make: 1254-055 Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.
"../Makefile.shared", line 40: make: 1254-055 Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.
"../Makefile.shared", line 41: make: 1254-055 Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.
make: 1254-058 Fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 2.
```

This appears when I execute `make world`. This is the final output from `./configure`:

```
Directories where Objective Caml will be installed:
        binaries.................. /usr/local/bin
        standard library.......... /usr/local/lib/ocaml
        manual pages.............. /usr/local/man (with extension .1)
Configuration for the bytecode compiler:
        C compiler used........... gcc
        options for compiling..... -fno-defer-pop -Wall -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_REENTRANT
        options for linking.......   -lm  -lcurses -lpthread
        shared libraries not supported
Configuration for the native-code compiler:
        (not supported on this platform)
Source-level replay debugger: supported
Additional libraries supported:
        unix str num dynlink bigarray systhreads threads graph dbm
Configuration for the "num" library:
        target architecture ...... generic (asm level 0)
Configuration for the "graph" library:
        options for compiling .... -I/usr/X11R7/include
        options for linking ...... -L/usr/X11R7/lib -lX11
The "labltk" library: not supported
** Objective Caml configuration completed successfully **
```

Comment: I just saw [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840144/how-i-can-compile-ocaml-in-unix-aix-step-by-step). Since you just want to compile a program that's written in Ocaml, I recommend trying [Christoph Bauer's port](http://home.arcor.de/chr_bauer/ocaml-aix.html) of Ocaml. Furthermore, since you aren't doing Ocaml programming, Stack Overflow is the wrong place for your question; it should be migrated to another site (do not repost!).

Answer (score 1):

AIX is no longer an [officially-supported platform](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/portability.en.html). There is an [unofficial port of OCaml 3.11.2](http://home.arcor.de/chr_bauer/ocaml-aix.html).

You can fix your immediate build error by using GNU make. Alternatively, you can try tweaking the makefile. `otherlibs/Makefile.shared` is using a non-standard construct `?=`; change the three lines to use `=`, i.e. `CMIFILES = $(CAMLOBJS:.cmo=.cmi)` and so on. You'll also need to change `otherlibs/num/Makefile` to move the line with the definition of `CMIFILES` below `include ../Makefile`, and similarly in `otherlibs/dbm/Makefile` and `otherlibs/str/Makefile` move the definition of `CLIBNAME` below `include ../Makefile`.

I recommend searching or posting on the [caml-list](http://caml.inria.fr/resources/forums.en.html). This is the best place to get in touch with other people who may still be using Ocaml on AIX.

Answer (score 0):

You should put full logs (on pastebin or whatever) and not cut arbitrary parts out!
Also show the output of `make --version` (GNU make should work).

Comment: yes i install `gmake` and after i install it `./configure` and `gmake world` it is appear execute successfully but i still have an error when i execute `gmake opt` and the error is `Makefile:23: *** missing separator.  Stop.` .... so what is the error now ???

Comment: Probably make is called recursively in ocaml's Makefile without `$(MAKE)`, but since you still don't include any logs I can't help you.